# Adjust UILabel font size for device dimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uilabel

Is there a way to set UILabel font to be greater in big device and smaller in small device?

Have I to do it programmatically, checking every time the device size?

My approach is this, now:

```
class func hightlightPtSize(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return height / 25
}

class func notSoHighlightPtSize(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return height / 30
}

class func stdPtSize(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return height / 35
}

class func sizeForType(height: CGFloat, type: Int) -> CGFloat {
    switch type {
    case STD:
        return stdPtSize(height: height)
    case HIGHLIGHT:
        return hightlightPtSize(height: height)
    case NOT_SO_HIGH:
        return notSoHighlightPtSize(height: height)
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can just use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth ` instead of this

Comment: You can determine by defining on what resolution are you designing the UI, say if your storyboard has dimension for iPhone 6, so fix the width to 375 and calculate change, when you run the device say for iPhone 5, which has width 320, you get the difference to `.85 by doing 320/375`, and if your fontsize was 14 for iPhone 6, you get 11.9 for iPhone 5 and bigger for bigger devices by multiplying the difference to actual fontsize ie 14*.85, so formula comes to `fontSize*(actualScreenWidth/designTimeScreenWidth)`

Comment: I can't figure what are you exactly facing, but I assume that there are many approaches to consider better than doing it manually... Checking the idea of [Intrinsic Content Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html) might be useful to your case.

Comment: Tj3n this is not exactly what I want. I would have three different sizes, to let the user understand quickly the structure of the view

Comment: iphonic it's an approach similar to the one I already use.. didn't Apple provide something better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solution for your problem. Below my code in Objective C.

```
float newFontSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * (fontSize / 568.0);
        if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height < 500) {
            newFontSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * (fontSize / 480.0);
        }
        self.label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.label.font.fontName size:newFontSize];
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: what do 480.0 and 568.0 mean?

Comment: increase the font size according to the ratio of device scaling by comparing UIScreen height with the current height of xib at design time. i have set 568 for bigger device then 5s and 480 for smaller device :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried before by making my default font for all labels larger than any possibility used - 60 in my case. Then set the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property to true to let the system size the font for me, while I set the `size` of my `UILabel`.

To make a label proportionate to the screen size you can use the autoresizing feature of storyboard. With the `UILabel` selected, if there is no existing constraints, you can see something like this:

[image]

In the right panel of Xcode, click the lines to toggle it on or off, the four line on the sides will tell if the view will maintain it's distance from the sides of it's `superview` the two in the square will tell if it resizes with it's `superview` in your case, make sure those are on as in the image above. As for the other four that I did not on, you can try experimenting toggling each on or off in combinations with others to find the exact behaviour you want.

If constraints are needed by it's siblings or super/sub views, I can suggest you try a set of constraints like:

- Label(width) equal to SuperView(width) - change the multiplier to set how much of the space you want to take
- Label(height) equal to SuperView(height) - same as width
- Label(leading) equal to SuperView(leading) - change constant to set distance from leading edge, can change to trailing edge if needed
- Label(Top) equal to SuperView(Top) same as leading, can change to bottom if needed.

It might be slightly verbose, but mainly take note of the first two to get the sizing, set the **multiplier** of the constraints not **constant**. The next two are mainly just to satisfy the requirements to properly place your label in the view. You can freely align centers or align top/bottom/leading/trailing in combinations to position it where you want.

Comment: and what if I have to use at least a constraint? i.e. the UILabel must use half of the total width

Comment: In your stated example you do not need that constraint. By setting the current size of the  `UILabel` to half that of your `UIView` and toggling the horizontal scaling(the line with two arrows pointing left and right), the `UILabel` will always resize itself to half of its `superview`. If there are other needs of constraints, you might need to wait awhile while I improve my answer to use constraints.

Answer (score 1):

My Swift version of kishan godhani's solution:

```
let screen = UIScreen.main
var newFontSize = screen.bounds.size.height * (defaultFont / 568.0);
if (screen.bounds.size.height < 500) {
    newFontSize = screen.bounds.size.height * (defaultFont / 480.0);
}
label.font = label.font.withSize(newFontSize)
```